# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP while sending an emoji through C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to sendkeys a emoji.I have tried to send it by coping the signal , but it raised this exception.

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP
```

Than i tried to send it as unicode, but without any success. its ain't the deisrable sign.

```
input.SendKeys("/u1F44D")
```

What is the proper way to send an emoji ?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to send the **emoji** i.e. ?? signal through `SendKeys()` method.

Taking out a leaf from @JimEvans [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787436/c-sharp-selenium-send-an-emoji-using-sendkeys), currently ChromeDriver only supports code points in the **Plane 0** i.e. the [Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)) at present.

Using *GeckoDriver/Firefox* or *IEDriverServer/IE* combo would have fetched you better results.

You can find the current status of the specific tests in the [Web Platform Test Suite](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GUK_sdY2cv59VAJNDxZQIfypnOpapSQhMjfcJ9Wc42U/edit#gid=0) that specifically send emojis and these work for other browsers too.

However, to send a **emoji** through C# you can use the following syntax:

```
input.SendKeys("\u1F44D");
```

Comment: Hope Chrome Driver will fix this soon

Comment: @Kostas Hope so

Comment: Hi! Any update you know about? I had ran into the same issue just recently.
The solution was `IJavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript(script, args)` but thanks to angular and ag-grid, it is followed by a slightly dark magic... :D

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in Javascript code**

```
    async sendKeysWithEmojis(element, text) {
        const script = `var elm = arguments[0],
        txt = arguments[1];elm.value += txt;
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown', {bubbles: true}));
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keypress', {bubbles: true}));
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {bubbles: true}));
        elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('keyup', {bubbles: true}));`;
        await this.driver.executeScript(script, element, text);
    }
```

**Call it like so**

```
const element = await this.driver.findElement(selector);
await sendKeysWithEmojis(element, ' This one shall pass ');
```

**What is happening here?**
We are emulating native key presses using events

Notice that the `{bubbles: true}` is optional (Was needed in my case due to a complex wrapped input)

Comment: Care to convert it to c#?

Comment: Haven't written in c# for years - but the above code should give you direction

Comment: I tried it but I get "unexpeted error" on "this.driver.findElement". the code doesn't recognize it.

Comment: Perhaps something like (Replace selector below):
`var driver = new ChromeDriver() { Url = "http://www.something.com" };

            var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@aria-label='Search']"));
PopulateElementJs(driver, searchInput, "");
`
Also make sure you have this function

`public static void PopulateElementJs(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element, string text)
        {
            var script = "arguments[0].value=' " + text + " ';";
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script, element);
        }
`