# How to send encoded text using Selenium ChromeDriver SendKeys

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, whatsapp

I am trying to automate sending messages via WhatsApp using Selenium. Here is the C# code, I have used and it throwing "**Error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP**"

The message has Emoji's and hyperlink and special characters.

`Insulated Lunch Bag❤️50% Off with Promo CODE ABCDEFGHIJ https://amazon.com/dp/B08ZMVC8QQ?tag=xcv2090-00`

## **What is the I have tried so far:**

```
string mesg = "Insulated Lunch Bag❤️50% Off with Promo CODE ABCDEFGHIJ
https://amazon.com/dp/B08ZMVC8QQ?tag=xcv2090-00";

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument(@"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\ABCD\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default");
            options.AddArgument(@"--profile-directory=Default");

            IWebDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), options);
            chromeDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/");
            chromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@title='UserName']")).Click();
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            var msgBox = chromeDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='p3_M1']"));
            Thread.Sleep(500);

msgBox.SendKeys(mesg);
```

## **What is the expectation:**

Formatted text in WhatsApp, here is the example:

78% off Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra Case Clip Coupon: 8% Coupon Code:  709M6CET  Final Price: $3.08Works only on the listed optionJust click the above code to copy it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53794684/14459189

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Selenium send an emoji using SendKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787436/c-sharp-selenium-send-an-emoji-using-sendkeys)

Comment: @GregBurghardt I tried as mentioned in that post but didn't work. Btw, I was using ChromeDriver.

Comment: I think the the main point of the other question is that this is not supported by ChromeDriver.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Is there any other driver that supports this? Please let me know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The other question I linked to has some suggestions.