# sendkeys error chrome driver emoji (ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP)

Tags: c#, xaml, selenium-webdriver

I have an application that has a richTextBox where I enter lyrics and emojis, then with a sendkeys I try to send the content to a web that has an input and the focus on it and the error it gives me is, ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP Would I have any other option to copy and paste the content? I have dealt with Clipboard.SetTex (Message) and nothing, I would like another way to send the message without using SendKeys ().

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439197/openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-chromedriver-only-supports-c/53810992#53810992) helps you?

Comment: what happens is that I have a form with a Richtextbox, I want to be able to send the content to another screen where I have an embedded webview type web that has an input with the active focus but doing it with sendkeys gives me that error, it does not matter if I solve the error thing what interests me is to be able to copy and paste the content from one place to another via code.

Comment: No, your original question isn't what you are mentioning with in your comments now :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but the main problem was with SendKeys (Message), so I would like to do it in another way, but if what I do is copy the contents of a RichTextBox to paste it or send it to an input of a web, there would be some way to do it without SendKeys ()