# Send Selenium emoji with C # project

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to send emojis through Selenium, but I can't.

My Project is C #, Selenium webdriver, Chromedriver.

My code:

```
 string Message = "";
 driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='_glo']/div")).SendKeys(Message);
```

Comment: What happens when you try to send emojis? Does it error? Does it output anything?

Comment: @GarrisonBecker, thanks.<p>
The erorr is: "unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chromedriver only supports characters in the BMP error while sending Emoji with ChromeDriver Chrome using Selenium Python to Tkinter's label() textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138825/chromedriver-only-supports-characters-in-the-bmp-error-while-sending-emoji-with)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439197/openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-chromedriver-only-supports-c

Comment: I try this:
              `                              //https://www.inviul.com/send-texts-get-texts-selenium/
                                            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
                                            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='_glo']/div"));
                                            js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value ='hello';", element);`

But there is no error, but neither write