# Selenium Chrome Driver(Python): Send emojis

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to send a emoji with python and the Selenium Chrome Driver when the following error accured:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP


(Session info: chrome=86.0.4240.75)
```

I already researched this topic for a while and found the following workaround in C# [in another Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439197/openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-chromedriver-only-supports-c/53810992) from @GalBracha.

Since I don't know C# at all and I am not too familiar with Selenium I wanted to ask if someone knows a similar solution in Python.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Google Images as an example here. You can replace `emoji` with the desired emoji unicode. You can find the codes [here](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://images.google.com/')

search = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input') 
JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT = """
  var elm = arguments[0], txt = arguments[1];
  elm.value += txt;
  elm.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  """

emoji = u'\U0001F600'

browser.execute_script(JS_ADD_TEXT_TO_INPUT, search, emoji)
```

The unicode will look lile `U+1F603`. All you need to do is replace the '+' with '000' with a `\` before the 'U' too look like `\U000F603`

Answer (score 6):

### **Copy & Paste it**

It was so easy to round on this issue by copying the text to the clipboard and then pasting it into the element.
[image: pasting a text that contains emojis]

```
import pyperclip
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://google.com")
title = driver.title
assert title == "Google"

driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

search_box = driver.find_element(by=By.NAME, value="q")

pyperclip.copy("Hi  This is a test message ! ")
act = ActionChains(driver)
act.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys("v").key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```